# rxjs combineLatest and Anguar2 change detection on Observable Arrays

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I am struggling a lot with some basic change detection inside my application. I have been at this for a couple of days and losing the will! I wonder if anyone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a `group` with 2 `user` lists. One is for `members` and the other is for `moderators`.

This method connects to the database to get a list of objects each with a `$key` value. Now I want to use those keys to go and get the actual `UserData` for each user. I tried everything and `combineLatest` is the only thing I could seem to get working.

So both call the function and I am using an `async` pipe on my template.

```
members$ = myService.getMemberListByType("blah", "members");
moderators$ = myService.getMemberListByType("blah", "moderators");
```

My function looks like this.

```
  private getMemberListByType(groupKey: string, memberType: string) {

    return this.af.database.list(`groups/${groupKey}/${memberType}`)
      .switchMap(userListKeyMap => {

        console.log("UserListKeyMap", memberType, userListKeyMap);

        let usersObservables: Observable<UserData>[] = [];
        userListKeyMap.forEach((object) => {
          usersObservables.push(this.af.database.object(`users/${object.$key}`)
            .map(UserData.fromJSON));
        });

        return Observable.combineLatest(usersObservables);
      });

  }
```

However, Angular does not detect changes to this list as following.  Say that a different method elsewhere removes a `member` and adds him to `moderator`. In this case, the `members` list is emitting a empty list of users `[]`.

My *ngIf and *ngFor do not detect changes with this new empty object. The result is that the user (on the template) is now part of 2 lists but the data under this is perfectly accurate as highlighted by the log.

I feel that when I combineLatest on an empty array, this is the source of my problem. Nothing can emit.... so how can Angular change? I don't know how to solve it though. Is there an alternative to combineLatest in this "empty" use case? Since I am using an `async` pipe, I need something that makes sense.

Would anyone be able to shine a light on my issue?

Thank you!

**Update**

I am convinced the problem is with angular2 not detecting an empty observable list. Specifically when an Observable Array has a value, but later that value becomes empty. Angular2 will not see the empty array. I have no way to solve this problem at this time. Either my approach is wrong, or something specific needs to happen to register an empty observable list?

[image: screen of problem]

1. Blue = The loaded state of the component is good, the user was a member.
2. Green = The user was moved from member to manager/moderator.
3. Red = This doesn't exist, so why is it still showing?

Comment: suggest you to have a look around this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584409/change-detection-in-angular-2/41585545#41585545

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is simple workaround:

```
  private getMemberListByType(groupKey: string, memberType: string) {

    return this.af.database.list(`groups/${groupKey}/${memberType}`)
      .switchMap(userListKeyMap => {

        console.log("UserListKeyMap", memberType, userListKeyMap);

        let usersObservables: Observable<UserData>[] = [];
        userListKeyMap.forEach((object) => {
          usersObservables.push(this.af.database.object(`users/${object.$key}`)
            .map(UserData.fromJSON));
        });

        return usersObservables.length > 0 ? Observable.combineLatest(usersObservables) : Observable.of([]);
      });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work!  For anyone who is confused, notice `combineLatest([])` with an empty array is valid but will never emit a value, whereas `of([])` does emit a value.  This is key to change detection in the template. I appreciate it Kemsky.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach seems correct to me. Using `combineLatest()` with an empty array shouldn't end with an error (similarly to eg. `forkJoin`, using empty array is a valid use-case). Then even if it completes because of an empty array you're using `switchMap` so this shouldn't be the problem I think.

I don't have any experience with AngularFire2 so I don't know whether `this.af.database.object` just emits all items **once and then completes** or **it emits a value on every change** (which is probably what you want if I guess).

Anyway a very common issue with using `combineLatest()` or `forkJoin()` is that their source Observables always have to **emit at least one item**. In other words if any of the `this.af.database.object` is empty then `combineLatest()` won't emit anything.

You can make sure there's always at least one value with `startWith()`. For example like the following:

```
userListKeyMap.forEach((object) => {
    usersObservables.push(this.af.database.object(`users/${object.$key}`)
        .startWith('{}')
        .map(UserData.fromJSON));
});
```

If this doesn't help try using just `Observable.timer()` instead of `this.af.database.object` or `this.af.database.list` to make sure Angular2 subscribes to it and keeps the subscription even when new items are emitted.

Comment: I refactored my comments here.  Thank you! Unfortunately, I couldn't get any of your suggestions to work, and I don't really want to use that `.startWith`. It was great to read up on it though! It is just that, there is nothing there and pretending there was seemed redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```ts
private getMemberListByType(groupKey: string, memberType: string) {

  return this.af.database.list(`groups/${groupKey}/${memberType}`)

           // Force the source obs to complete to let .toArray() do its job.
           .take(1)

           // At this point, the obs emits a SINGLE array of ALL users.
           .do(userList => console.log(userList))

           // This "flattens" the array of users and emits each user individually.
           .mergeMap(val => val)

           // At this point, the obs emits ONE user at a time.
           .do(user => console.log(user))

           // Load the current user
           .mergeMap(user => this.af.database.object(`users/${user.$key}`))

           // At this point, the obs emits ONE loaded user at a time.
           .do(userData => console.log(userData))

           // Transform the raw user data into a User object.
           .map(userData => User.fromJSON(userData))

           // Store all user objects into a SINGLE, final array.
           .toArray();

}
```

Note. The lines starting with `do()` are only here to explain what's going on. No need to keep them in the final code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew my lame attempt had to be at the core of the issue. I would love a tutorial series just explained like that rather than the rxjs docs. The only problem I am having now is that I cant subscribe to a response. I see your trace statements in do but oddly `this.groupService.getGroupManagerList(groupKey).subscribe(success => console.log(success))` does not fire (or error) which is very strange.

Comment: Very strange indeed. If you see the logs in the console, it means the observable is executed. Are you sure you're subscribing to the right method? Your initial code mentioned `getMemberListByType()` and now you say `getGroupManagerList()`.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for the confusion! I don't access this method directly, but have some other methods to return it so I can hide the string types.  Basically it is the same thing. It is just odd how neither my `async` pipe reacts to it, nor my subscribe above. Not does it error, or is it undefined when I subscribe, plus I see your executing `do's`  I am checking out why now as I have never seen this before.

Comment: one last question. I added a `.do` after `toArray()` at the bottom of your method. `.do(x => console.log(x))` and I don't see that step either. Is `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray'` the correct import?

Comment: The two issues you mention as errors are actually both correct. **1.** `Observable<UserData>[]` is correct. It means an array of `Observable<UserData>` objects (Observables emitting `UserData` objects). He wants to use an array so he can pass it to `combineLatest()`. **2.** The `combineLatest()` operator has also its static variant. See static methods at the top of http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: Fascinating. I completely missed that, thanks for clarifying Martin. I'll update the answer to avoid confusing any more people.

Comment: @Clark. Yup that's correct. I think I figured out what happened. I'm pretty sure `toArray()` does its job once the source observable completes. But Firebase observables don't complete, they keep listening. Try adding `.take(1)` at the top of the chain to see if it helps? (see updated answer) It might not be what you want, but if we can pinpoint the problem, it'll be easier to find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it next. The only thing that concerns me is that I was using `take(1)` as "take one and then unsubscribe".  However, that isn't the case here.  If I do that, the observable will die?  So if you are looking at this list, and a member joins the group in real time, or a member by another admin becomes a moderator... None of these updates will fire any more? In other words... it will never complete and `toArray` probably will not fire

Comment: That's correct. take(1) will force the obs to complete. Like in said in my previous comment, this might not be what you want but I was just trying to figure out why toArray() isn't working. Baby steps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using forkJoin on the list of observables

```js
let userListKeyMap$ = Rx.Observable.of([{key:1}, {key:2}, {key:3}]); //mock keys
let requestUserFromKey = (key) => Rx.Observable.of({user: key}).delay(1000); //mock users

let result$ = userListKeyMap$.switchMap((userKeys) => 
 Rx.Observable.forkJoin(userKeys.map(uk => requestUserFromKey(uk.key))));

result$.subscribe((users) => console.log('got some users: ', users));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Corolla thanks! I was able to massage this into the same context, but I don't think that the observable creation is the problem. Even with your suggestion, Angular2 won't detect an empty array.  (See Screenshot in my question above).