# data from @Output updates to binding in HTML but not in expression logic or console.log()

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use data received through an `@Output` to trigger if statements inside my component.  For testing purposes I have this in the template

```
{{selectedAnswer | json}}
```

When I select answers in the child component this binding works in the parent component showing the data is reaching the variable `selectedAnswer`.  Yet when I do `console.log(this.selectedAnswer)` nothing logs.

I've also been trying to get it to update to a variable to run the if conditions.  When the page first loads it picks up the value of the first radio button when I don't have any selected by default.  When I click through them the value updates in the test binding but nothing changes in the console.logs.

This is what's going on in the parent component.

```
//data coming in from @Output in child component
public selectedI(selected){ this.selectedAnswer = selected };

//the variable I'm passing it into for use.
selectedAnswer: any;

ngOnChanges() {

    //my way so far of attempting to get the value I want when a selection is made.
    var trigger = this.selectedAnswer? this.selectedAnswer.value1: '';



    console.log(this.selectedAnswer);
}
```

Template

```
<multiple-choice-radio *ngIf="expbTrigger"
    [question]  = "question01"
    (selectedO) = "selectedI($event)"
></multiple-choice-radio>
```

The only thing different in calling it here vs. calling it in the binding is the binding has a `|json` pipe added to it.  Am I suppose to be doing the same thing somehow inside the expression?  The way the data is being collected in the child component is like this

```
@Output() selectedO: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

//variable for storing values from (click) event
selected = {value1: '', value2: ''};

//(click) event that gets values from template and passes them into "selected"
getSelected(ans) {
    this.selected = { value1: ans.id, value2: ans.answer };
}

//(click) event that sends @Output data to parent component.
public sendAnswer = (): void => {
     this.selectedO.emit(this.selected);
 }
```

Template

```
<input type="radio"
    [attr.name]  = "quesForm.value.name"
    [attr.id]    = "ans.id"
    [attr.value] = "ans.answer"
    (click)      = "getSelected(ans)"
    (click)      = "sendAnswer()"
    hidden
/>
```

I've personally been feeling the way I'm doing all this is a bit bulky so if you know of a cleaner way to do this please share.  Other than that, how can I get this to log in the console as well as be accessible for further use in triggering logic upon updates?

Comment: update the post with your html markups

Comment: just updated it

Comment: why do you have two click handlers in your HTML?

Comment: like I said, I felt this was a little bulky, but it's the only way so far that I've come up with where the data flows the way I want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SimpleChanges in angular2

```
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core'
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);// to log if any changes are detected.

}
```

Possible mistake

1. Your **this.selected** is not a input property

Note: Angular calls its **ngOnChanges** method whenever it detects changes to input properties of the component (or directive).

Alternatively, if you are **assigning** the variable to some DOM element using [ngModel] you can trigger (ngModelChange) event manually.

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange($event)" />
```

You need to handle the method as

```
onSelectedChange(val){
     .....
}
```

## Best Practice

Among all other alternatives when you are handling an **@output** property you are using a method in your component and **you can place all your logic into that method** itself instead of using the above.

Check out **ngDoCheck** and **ChangeDetectionStrategy** to detect all changes you can use **[this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584409/change-detection-in-angular-2/41585545#41585545)**. But **ngDoCheck()** checks for mouse and keyboard events which causes great overhead.

Comment: is there anything else I'm suppose to import?  It's throwing an error saying it can't find `SimpleChanges`

Comment: I'm passing the `this.selected` into the `event`, it was the only way I could get the data to even show in the parent component.

Comment: and `SimpleChanges` isn't detecting anything from `selectedAnswer`

Comment: I've been reading the answer you linked it to and checking more into the `ngDoCheck`, thanks for the info.

Comment: mark this answer and upvote both too as it helped you. :)

Comment: if you need some more clarifications I can help you through team viewer as well.

Comment: @Optiq your expectation is achieved or need more information on it?

Comment: actually I've been studying a lot and was just about too post another question to figure out how to call my data in a way to where I don't need to use the Elvis Operator with virtually every piece of data so I can actually apply what I learn in the way I learned it and not have go through all this extra stuff just to figure out how to add a `?` properly so it doesn't throw errors.

Comment: So was this  help ful?

Comment: I just upvoted it because I did get some info from it that shed light on some things, but it also pushed me to look more into the way I'm doing other things.  So I'm just taking it a step at a time and haven't gotten back to this point yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a radio button list, and handle a click event when the user clicks an answer, I would set it up this way:

**Interfaces**

```
interface Choice {
    id:number,
    name:string;
}

interface Question {
    text: string;
    choices: Choice[];
}
```

**Child Component**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <div>
            {{ question.text }}
        </div>

        <div *ngFor="let option of question.choices">
            <input type="radio" (click)="selectOption(option)" name="options" [value]="option.id">{{option.name}}<br>
       </div>

    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() question: Question;
    @Output() selected: EventEmitter<Choice>;
    constructor() {
        this.selected = new EventEmitter<Choice>();
    }

    selectOption(choice:Choice) {
        this.selected.next(choice);
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        Options: 
        <child [question]="question" (selected)="onSelect($event)" ></child>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {
    question: Question;
    constructor() {
        this.question = {
            text: "what is 1+1?",
            choices: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Choice 1'}, 
                { id: 2, name: 'Choice 2'}, 
                { id: 3, name: 'Choice 4'}, 
                { id: 4, name: 'Choice 8'} 
            ]
        };
    }

    onSelect(choice:Choice) {
        alert(choice.id);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!